# JAVA Map return unexcepted key and sorting

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, key

I have in the restaurant class

```
...
private Map<String, Race> races = new HashMap<>(); 
private List<Party> parties = new LinkedList<>();

public Map<Race, Integer> statComposition() {
    return parties.stream().flatMap(p->p.getComp().entrySet().stream()) 
            .collect(toMap(e->e.getKey(), e->e.getValue(), (s,a)->s + a));
...
```

and in the party class there are

```
...
private Map<Race, Integer> comp = new HashMap<>();

public void addCompanions(Race race, int num) {
    if(!races.containsKey(race)) {
        races.put(race, num);
    }else{
        races.put(race, races.get(race) + num);
        }
}

public Map<Race, Integer> getComp() {return comps;} 
...
```

both the value is indicated the number of companions

but when I run the main class, the `statComposition` returns something like

```
{it.polito.oop.milliways.Race@15db9742 = 3, it.polito.oop.milliways.Race@6d06d69c = 2}
```

where the it.polito.oop.milliways is the package name, and the correct one should be

```
{Amoeboid Zingatularians=3, Betelgeusians=2}
```

why it like this?

sorry for the bad title, I really don't know how to describe this.

also in this case how could I sort the map `statComposition` by key?

Comment: The key in `comp` map is a `Race` object and that is what is used as key for final `statComposition` map. Where "Amoeboid Zingatularians" are you expecting should come from.

Comment: Do you have a toString defined for Race class?

Comment: @clinomaniac I had a getName() in Race class, but if I use e->e.getKey().getName(), it cause Type mismatch

Comment: Your hashmap is fine. The only problem you have is to print a readable Race. You can fix that by implementing the toString() function for the Race class and choose what you need to print there. It seems that you need it to print the name so I would return the getName() from the toString() function. Another thing is that HashMaps are not ordered. If you need the map to be ordered I would use a TreeMap or something and define the order.

Answer (score 0):

Where you say `e->e.getKey()`, you are getting the `Race` object.  When you attempt to print an `Object` (which `Race` is, like all non-primatives in Java), it prints the `toString()` implementation of that object.  The default `toString()` implementation is defined in `Object` (as the full class name along with hex object identifier; what you're seeing).  This default is used if you do not override `toString()` for your object.  You have options from here:

**1**: Override `toString()` in `Race`:

```
public class X extends Race {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "X-Name";  // Or, if directly in race, the variable containing the name.
    }
}
```

**2**: Call the appropriate method that defines the races name.  IE: if that method is `getName()`:

```
public Map<String, Integer> statComposition() {
    return parties.stream().flatMap(p->p.getComp().entrySet().stream()) 
            .collect(toMap(e->e.getKey().getName(), e->e.getValue(), (s,a)->s + a));
```

Note that option 1 is not a good pick unless the only defining attribute of a race is its name.  I would probably give preference to option 2 in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your option 2 before but in that case it caused "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Race,Integer>"

Comment: @kaeruu0087 I updated the answer.  If you go the route of option 2, you would want to return a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of `Map<Race, Integer>`.  Alternatively, you can still return a `Map<Race, Integer>`, and wherever you would go to print it, get the `String` name from the `Race` object (do not simply try to print the Map as is; it will not give you what you want unless you do option 1, which, again, is a bad idea unless you meet the criteria specified).

Comment: yes but the frame was given, and I am not allowed to change it.

Comment: Then implement a *separate* method that converts your `Map<Race, Integer>` to `Map<String, Integer>`?  Or just implement a separate method that parses and prints the contents of your `Map<Race, Integer>` for the appropriate fields (namely, the `String` name and the `Integer` count).